# NSString stringWithFormat added "ffffff"

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdata

I'm trying to get bytes from NSData and put it in NSString. While I doing this "ffffff" added simultaneously :

```
char *array = (char *)[deviceInfo bytes];
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x", array[5],array[4],array[3],array[2],array[1],array[0]];
```

returns "53:ffffffcb:ffffffb8:51:09:fffffff0"

Comment: What happens if you declare `array` correctly with `uint8_t *array = ...`?

Comment: Yes it works! I will use unsigned char instead. Pls, add like an answer your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue relates to *sign extension* as the compiler promotes your `signed char` to `unsigned int`. The numbers with `fffff` are negative.  The `%x` format expects an `unsigned int` argument.

Declaring `array` correctly will fix the issue:

```
const uint8_t *array = [deviceInfo bytes];
```